# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac n{n^2+1}+\frac n{n^2+2}+\frac n{n^2+3}+\dots+\frac n{n^2+n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Here is a question:
Show that the limit exists and find it
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac n{n^2+1}+\frac n{n^2+2}+\frac n{n^2+3}+\dots+\frac n{n^2+n}\right)$$
I'm finding it a bit tricky to evaluate the limit of this series. I tried finding the limit of each term, but I think that's not the correct approach. How should I go about solving it? Can I use squeeze theorem here? If so, then how?